# Cron jobs and cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cron

I have looked around and I really cannot find an answer.
I am very new to this, and I want to run a cron job in cakephp from the command line. I have made my shell, and tested it manually and it all works. Now I would just like to make it run every 10  minutes but I need to do this from the command line only.

Please help! Thanks :)

Comment: What's wrong with http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html ?

Comment: Also note that the above link as well as [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/24/cakephp-console-on-linux-systems) can be found via google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open your consol as root account and run this command line **crontab-e**
2. add this line at the end of file */10 * * * * php /path_to_your_script.php
3. Save changes

Thanks